# How to use GroupBy in CAML and produce lists with headings for each group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript

Using SharePoint's javascript object model, I'm looking for a way to group records in unordered lists with their category (what they're grouped by) as a heading on top. I have gotten so far as to group my records, but do not know how to add a heading to the top for each group set.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Title" Type="text" /></OrderBy><GroupBy Collapse="TRUE"><FieldRef Name="myGroup" Type="text" /></GroupBy></Query></View>');
```

and that produces something like this:

**Group A**

- Record

**Group A**

- Record

**Group A**

- Record

**Group B**

- Record

**Group B**

- Record

**Group B**

- Record

--------- however, I'm looking to do something like this ---------

**Group A**

- Record
- Record
- Record

**Group B**

- Record
- Record
- Record

I have a feeling there's going to be a for each in here somewhere, but I cannot find how you iterate through each group. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: What does the code look like where you deal with the returned item collection?

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to the category of the first item returned. As you iterate through each item compare it to the value of the variable. If the value is the same then we're in the same heading, else start a new heading.

```
current_category = category of first item
print current_category as heading
for each item
    if current_category == category of current item
        print current item details as sub-list
    else
        current_category = category of current item
        print current-category as heading
```